# How to get APN name in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing one application in which i want to know how to retrieve APN name so please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you need this...??
Please provide more information...

Comment: AS i am having 2 Wi Fi in my area so currently I am using which wi fi that i want to know about...please help me

Comment: Try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443946/how-to-detect-available-apn-settings

Answer (score 1):

You can get Apn setting as following code:

```
ServiceRecord st = new  net.rim.device.api.servicebook.ServiceRecord();
System.out.println("APN Setting: "+st.getAPN());
```

Comment: `st.getAPN()` is returning null even though I've set the name in TCP/IP configuration.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Access-and-Obtain-Service-Books-on-a-device/ta-p/444756